# Crystal Report charts with strings

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, charts, crystal-reports

I'm trying to create a chart in crystal reports that displays count(x) on change of A , B

it's supposed to show number of merchants "count(x)" who paid "B" for each region "A"

the problem is that on Data tab in chart expert, on the available fields, it shows only the numeric fields "e.g: region ID / payers ID"  while i want it on change of names not ID

*Note: they're already displayed on the report so it's not a connection/command problem

Comment: describe and clarify more, what is `A, B A,B`? what's the `cunt(x)`? what specifications of the `string` you want to `display` in chart? your question is `ambiguous`. `specify exactly what's the question and exactly what do you want` to do?

Comment: whatever what i want to do ,,, the problem is the same: "the records exist in table but not displayed on the "available fields" box to choose the data that i want to display on chart !" 

I've edited the question anyway, so if there's anything not clear . please tell me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to check all the types that CR accepts in charts and it were numbers / date / varchar

the fields in my DB was "nVarchar(MAX)" I tried to change it from DB, but CR didn't get affected by this change (God knows why!) and also even if it got affected this will result in other problems , so I thought about changing the type from the CR itself and it really worked

**right click on "Formula fields" > New > name your field
then in formula workshop write:

CStr ({table_name.field_name})**

while creating your chart, made it on change of the field you've created

I hope it helps as I've made a lot f research and came across many facing the same problem without a working solution